# Write permission to Linux folder shared via Samba

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, putty, samba

**Scenario:**

1. ASP.NET MVC 3 application
2. Window Server 2008
3. IIS 7
4. Network Mapped Drive( Z:/ with IP to the share folder named `Samba` of Linux machine.
5. PuTTY application

**Problem**

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application to upload a file to a network mapped drive i.e. a shared folder via Samba but it shows the error

> Access is denied

… while uploading the file to that folder. I can't provide write permissions to that folder from the *Security* options.

**Question**

How can I provide write permissions to that Samba shared folder for a specific user like the `NETWORK` service?

Can I do this from PuTTY? What are the steps? I'm a Linux novice.

Comment: What about your Samba configuration? Can you write anything at all to that folder from Windows? Please post the Samba configuration here.

Comment: This question is **way too general**. There is no such thing as "the LINUX". Every *distribution* of Linux is unique, and has unique functionality, commands, programs, versions, etc. Why did you say "Windows Server 2008", but only mention "Linux"? If you asked for help from someone and only told them "I am running Windows", would they be able to help you? Probably not -- they'd want to know the version, and whether it's server or client, etc. We need the same details for Linux, but even more, because there are multiple **distributions**. Please learn what you're doing first.